# Connection with peripheral device breaks after switching views

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a adafruit ( its a arduino based board ) with BLE on board. I am creating an app to be able to talk to it. I have managed to get a list of all the bluetooth devices and I can tap on the adafruit bluetooth device and connect with it. The bluetooth device indicates that a connection is established and when I go to another view the connection breaks. I am at the point where I don't know what I should do to preserve the connection until I manually break it or when the device shuts down.

Right now I only have a tableview that shows the available devices with BLE and I can tap on them to connect. Therefore I use the following code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let device = devices[indexPath.row]

    if let connectedDevice = Settings.getConnectedDevice() {
        if connectedDevice == device.identifier?.UUIDString {
            manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(device.peripheral)
            Settings.removeConnectedDevice()
            Settings.setIsConnected(false)
        }
    }
    else {
        manager.connectPeripheral(device.peripheral, options: nil)
        Settings.setConnectedDevice((device.identifier?.UUIDString)!)
        Settings.setIsConnected(true)
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to create a custom inherited from `NSObject` class that is specifically handles your BLE devices. You can create it's singleton object. You will be able to access this class from whole application using static shared instance. And your connection will also be preserved until you disconnects the device.

Comment: Will a singleton be always active in iOS?

Comment: Until you destroy or assign null value it will remain active. in objective-c somethings like this 
`+(instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static AppiBeacons *objAppiBeacons;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        objAppiBeacons = [[AppiBeacons alloc] init];
    });
    return objAppiBeacons;
}`
And you can access this class object using 
`[AppiBeacons sharedInstance]`

Comment: Is it a good practice to create the singleton in the same class or create a new class for it?

Comment: I would suggest to create separate class. In future if the code size increase, it will be easy to handle stuff.